# Block some selected Menu-Points in Android for Parental Control

Tags: java, android, kotlin, settings

Is it possible to build a Android-App,
where a User can control or block some selected menu-points in the default Android Settings menu? For example Connections or Display.

Sorry, I am completley new in Android Development. I want to develop an app for Parental Control.

Thank you :-)

Iam learning Kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no way to do this.  And remember-  there isn't one settings app.  Multiple OEMs write their own, or customize the base one.  So even if you could do it in the AOSP version, there's no way to be sure that the others would work with it.  If you need this for personal use, consider a custom ROM or replacing the settings app yourself.  If this is for a store app, its just not going to work, look into device ownership and device profiles as the only real way to prevent (some) settings changes.